# How to report session for active users while running Android foreground service

Tags: android, android-service, google-fabric

I'm using Fabric Answers for monitoring users. A foreground service with notification is running on my Android app after finishing app. I tried 2 ways to check a session for the number of active users.

[image]

case 1:

1. Open app - Active Users is 1
2. Start foreground service and finish app - Active Users is 1
3. 5 minutes later - **Active Users is 0**

case 2:

1. Open app - Active Users is 1
2. finish app with no foreground service - Active Users is 1
3. 5 minutes later - **Active Users is 0**

How can I make user's session alive? is there anyone to help this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todd from Fabric. Right now we don't have a way of extending the session beyond 5 minutes after foreground activity has completed. This means for music players, etc. sessions will end before the user has stopped listening. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was waiting for it. I have one more question. If I implement one event in background service, answers track it and make a session for an active user?